# Do Bluetooth headphones record phone call audio to themselves or to the paired computer or phone?

Tags: windows, android, bluetooth, headphones

Do Bluetooth headphones like galaxy buds or surface headphones record audio from phone calls to the headphones themselves, or to A location/buffer on the paired phone or computer?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you making the call?

Comment: Headphones usually don't record anything.

Comment: Headphones like you describe don't record anything since they don't have the necessary storage required to do that.

Comment: Wireless headphones have very limited battery, also they typically don't contain flash or larger RAM memory where they could store recordings. So why should a device be manufactured with additional components that cost money for something that is not a feature announced to the users?